# Dynamically changing the color of the text and links for Twitter API @username

Tags: jquery, api, twitter

I am working on the social media part of a website and my requirement allows the user to change the color of the background and text he is using for twitter window.I have partly achieved it but,when the **tweets are loaded dynamically** a css associated with the text is loaded each time making my changes null.
      I used jquery to add the color using **farbtastic.js** it works but partly.How can I avoid the dynamic loading of the css that is applied to the API or override the default color on each tweet load??Any links or pointers would help.
This is how I apply the css to the paragraph element of the tweets!

```
    if(container.className == 'tweetCPTrans'){
    $('p').attr('style', 'color:'+fb.color+' !important');      
 }

     twMix = new TWTR.Widget({ version: 4,
     type: 'profile', 
     rpp: 4, 
     interval: 6000, 
     width: w, 
     height: h, 
     theme: { shell: 
      { background: 'none', 
        color: '#4c4c4c' }, 
      tweets: { 
      background: '#none', 
      color: '#4c4c4c', 
     links: '#b30009' } }
```

Thanks
Sach

Comment: Not getting a fix yet!! I have updated the question with details.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you want.

```
complete : function (tweetBox) {

  me.tweetBox = tweetBox; 

  try {

     me.tweetBox.$editor.css({

        resize : 'none', 

        color : '#9B9B9B', 

        'font-family': 'Arial', 

        'font-size': '14px', 

        border : 'none', 

        background : 'transparent', 

        'border-radius': 0, 

        '-webkit-border-radius': 0, 

        '-moz-border-radius': 0 

     }); 

     me.tweetBox.$button.css( {

        cursor : 'hand', 

        cursor : 'pointer' 

     }); 

  } catch (e) {

     //

  }
```

}

This is the `complete` callback for the `tweetbox` method.

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply,but where should I add the callback?? I have the **social_media.js and add_twit.js and widjet.js** files as the api files.The add_twit.js file has the function with color assigned to the text and links like this `twMix =  new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 4,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: w,
  height: h,
  theme: {
   shell: {
    background: 'none',
    color: '#4c4c4c'
   },
   tweets: {
    background: '#none',
    color: '#4c4c4c',
    links: '#b30009'
   }
  }` I have not worked on it earlier so sorry if it sounds stupid!!